# Excel: how to generate serial number every time when the adjacent column hits a new character

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet like the following:

```
 name
 Pete
 CR
 123
 1255
 ... a couple rows of numbers
 Total
 Anna
 CR
 ... a couple rows of numbers
 Total 
 Ann
 CR
 ...
```

What I would like to achieve is to generate an id number for each person and the resulting rows being blank and the ideal result will be like this:

```
 id     name
 1      Pete
        CR
        123
        1255
        ... a couple rows of numbers
        Total
 2      Anna
        CR
       ... a couple rows of numbers
       Total 
 3     Ann
       CR
```

Comment: Just to verify, the persons name, beside which you want an ID number to be displayed, is always just above CR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1)  Insert a blank column to the left of your data column lets assume this makes Column A a blank column and column B your data list.

Step 2)  Fill in your header.  In cell A1 enter "id"

Step 3)  Enter the following formula in A2 and copy down.

```
=IF(B3="CR",COUNTIF($B$3:B3,"CR"),"")
```

It places an incremental number in column A in row above "CR" in column B.

Proof of concept:

[image]